# My CustomListview with checkboxes auto check them on scrolling

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Here is my class code:

```
class ExtrasPreviewClass
{
    [PrimaryKey]

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ExtrasName { get; set; }
    public string ExtrasCheckBox { get; set; }
    public string ExtrasPrice { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:weightSum="100"
android:minHeight="25px">
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Εξτρα"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtrasName"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Τιμή"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtrasPrice"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="ID"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtrasID"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtrasCheckBox"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
   </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

And here is my custom listview adapter

```
namespace WiOrderAndroid
{
class MyListViewAdapterExtras : BaseAdapter<ExtrasPreviewClass>
{
    public List<ExtrasPreviewClass> mitems;
    private Context mContext;
    public MyListViewAdapterExtras(Context context, List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mContext = context;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override ExtrasPreviewClass this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
        db.CreateTable<ExtrasPreviewClass>();



        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExtrasPreview, null, false);

        }



        TextView txtExtrasName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasName);
        txtExtrasName.Text = mitems[position].ExtrasName;
        CheckBox txtExtrasCheckBox = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasCheckBox);
        txtExtrasCheckBox.Text =mitems[position].ExtrasCheckBox;
        TextView txtExtrasID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasID);
        txtExtrasID.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].id);
        TextView txtExtrasPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasPrice);
        txtExtrasPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].ExtrasPrice);


        db.DeleteAll<ExtrasPreviewClass>();
        Connection.Extras = "";


        txtExtrasCheckBox.Click += delegate
        {
            if (txtExtrasCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                ExtrasPreviewClass tbl = new ExtrasPreviewClass();

                tbl.ExtrasName = txtExtrasName.Text;
                tbl.id = Convert.ToInt32(txtExtrasID.Text);
                db.Insert(tbl);

                double a, b, c;
                a = double.Parse(Connection.RetailPrice);
                b = double.Parse(txtExtrasPrice.Text);
                c = a + b;
                Connection.RetailPrice = c.ToString();


            }
            else
            {

                var data = db.Table<ExtrasPreviewClass>();
                int idvalue = Convert.ToInt32(txtExtrasID.Text);

                var data1 = data.Where(x => x.id == idvalue).FirstOrDefault();

                if (data1.id != null)
                {
                    db.Delete(data1);


                }
                double a, b, c;
                a = double.Parse(Connection.RetailPrice);
                b = double.Parse(txtExtrasPrice.Text);
                c = a - b;
                Connection.RetailPrice = c.ToString();
            }
        };

        return row;
```

So the problem is that, if i will check any of my my checkboxes and i will scrolling down i will see checkboxes witch they have been checked automatically. Also I'm using sqlite, and it insert duplicate values inside my table.Why happen this?

Comment: Check this for your problem solution - http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one `boolean` variable in `ExtrasPreviewClass` Class and maintain their state according position of selected and unselected items in list.

And set value of that variable in Checkbox .and update flag values in bean class for particular list item rather updating only `CheckBox`.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

See below `getView` Function in which

```
holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
```

name is Checkbox Object and flag value is taken from country object that is data list item.

And when onClick listenar runs

```
  country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
```

flag is reset from ChekBox Value in data list .

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

   if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
   holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
     public void onClick(View v) {  
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
      Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();  
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
       " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
     }  
    });  
   } 
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Country country = countryList.get(position);
   holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
   holder.name.setText(country.getName());
   holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
   holder.name.setTag(country);

   return convertView;

  }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you sir can you give me an example? you mean to make boolean my check box?  public boolean ExtrasCheckBox { get; set; }  ???/

Comment: no you need to take one `paramaeter` in your data list like your other data and set that `boolean` value in `CheckBox` .

Comment: Can you give me an example? You mean something like this?class ExtrasPreviewClass
    {
        [PrimaryKey]

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string ExtrasName { get; set; }
        public string ExtrasCheckBox { get; set; }
        public string ExtrasPrice { get; set; }
        public Boolean CheckboxState { get; set; }

    }

Comment: yes exactly same. and please see above link that is clear you a concept   .

Comment: Sorry but i didnt figure it out.If you got time let me know,if you could check this for me.